# Add anchor tag dynamically to page as pop up while onclick

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, anchor

Trying to add an `<a>` tag in the below `<div>` after submit button.

```js
$("div#idSection").append('<a href=http://localhost/request+{argument passed dynamically after clicking on submit button}+' onclick = "window.open('href=http://localhost/request+{argument passed dynamically after clicking on submit button}'">REPORT</a>);
```

```html
<div align="center" id="idSection">
  <input type="text" id="first" placeholder="Enter id here..." maxlength="11" />
  <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to append an  tag to a  element after a submit button is clicked, and you are passing an argument dynamically to the href attribute of the  tag. Your approach is almost correct, but there are a few issues with the syntax of the code you've provided:

- The href attribute in the  tag should be enclosed in quotation marks.
- You are using ' onclick' instead of ' onClick'
- You are trying to use the variable passed dynamically inside the single quotes of the window.open function, you should use it like this:

  window.open(href=http://localhost/request+${argument})

Here's an updated version of the code:

```js
$("div#idSection").append(`<a href="http://localhost/request+${argument}" onClick="window.open(href)" >REPORT</a>`);
```

This approach should work as long as the variable "argument" is defined and contains the correct value when the submit button is clicked.

Also, it's worth noting that, using window.open() might not be the best approach as it can be blocked by pop-up blockers and it may cause the browser to open the link in a new window or tab, which may not be desirable. You may consider using window.location.href or router.push() instead.

In summary, this approach is correct but needs some syntax and formatting changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if this suits your requirement. Do run it on your machine as attribute "target" in anchor tag will not work on below code snippet.

```js
$("#submit").click(function () {
  var id = $("#first").val();
  console.log(id);
  
  var requestURL = "http://localhost/request?id=" + id;
  console.log(requestURL);
  
  var anchorTag = '<a href="' + requestURL + '" target="_blank">REPORT</a>';
  console.log(anchorTag);

  $("div#idSection").append(anchorTag);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div align="center" id="idSection">
  <input type="text" id="first" placeholder="Enter id here..." maxlength="11" />
  <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague. Where you have in your code "{argument passed dynamically after clicking on submit button}", I will assume you mean the contents of the text input with id "first" and when the appended `<a>` tag is clicked that the URL you specified needs to be appended with `?id=the-value-of-the-id-text-widget'.

When the `<a>` tag is clicked, there should be no need to use the JavaScript `open` function to go to the new URL; it's sufficient to have the URL specified as the *href* argument:

```js
$( "#submit" ).click(function( event ) {
  let id = $('#first').val();
  let url = '<a id="a" href="http://localhost/request?id=' + id + '">REPORT</a>';
  // Get rid of any previous <a> tag:
  if ($('#a')) {
      $('#a').remove();
  }
  $('#idSection').append($(url));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div align="center" id="idSection">
        <input type="text" id="first"  placeholder="Enter id here..." maxlength="11" />
        <input type="button" id="submit"  value="Submit" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this requirement in a pure vanilla JavaScript.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const sbmtBtn = document.getElementById('submit');

sbmtBtn.addEventListener("click", addLink);

function addLink() {
  const inputVal = document.getElementById('first').value.trim();
  const linkElement = document.getElementById('link');
  
  if(linkElement) linkElement.remove();
  
  if (inputVal) {
    const anchorElement = `<a id="link" href="http://localhost/request?id=${inputVal}" target="_blank"> LINK </a>`;
    document.getElementById("submit").insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", anchorElement);
  } else {
    alert('ID field is required');
  }
}
```

```html
<div align="center" id="idSection">
  <input type="text" id="first"  placeholder="Enter id here..." maxlength="11" />
  <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#submit").click(function () {
  var id = $("#first").val();
  console.log(id);
  
  var requestURL = "https://localhost/request?id=" + id;
  console.log(requestURL);
  
  var anchorTag = '<a href="" onclick="window.open(\''+requestURL+'\', \'_blank\')">REPORT</a>'; 
  console.log(anchorTag);

  $("div#idSection").append(anchorTag);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div align="center" id="idSection">
        <input type="text" id="first"  placeholder="Enter id here..." maxlength="11" />
        <input type="button" id="submit"  value="Submit" />
</div>
```

Comment: Perhaps this could help

Comment: window.open as pop up

Answer (score 0):

```js
function clicked() {
    const id = document.getElementById('first').value;
    console.log(id);
    const requestURL = `https://localhost/request?id=${id}`;
    console.log(requestURL);
    const anchorTag = '<a href="" onclick="window.open(\'' + requestURL + '\', \'_blank\')">REPORT</a>';
    console.log(anchorTag);
    document.getElementById('idSection').innerHTML += (anchorTag);
}
```

```html
<div align="center" id="idSection">
  <input type="text" id="first" placeholder="Enter id here..." maxlength="11" />
  <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit" onclick="clicked()" />
</div>
```